# Laravel 10 - Extend existing artisan command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Let's say, for example, I want to add a couple of options to `php artisan migrate`:

```
php artisan migrate --core
php artisan migrate --project=0f9ebA2
```

Is it possible to extend an existing artisan command? I don't want to change any default behavior, just add options. It would be sufficient to have a wrapper class that pre-sets certain options, like changing a config variable or adding a path argument, then passes through everything else to the artisan function as normal.

Stubbed out, `php artisan migrate --core` would look something like:

```
public function handle() {
    $this->call('migrate', ['--path' => '/database/migrations/core', ...$this->arguments()]);
}
```

Stubbed out, `php artisan migrate --project=0f9ebA2` would look something like:

```
public function handle() {
    config(['tenant.key' => $this->argument('--project')]);
    $this->call('migrate', ['--path' => '/database/migrations/project', ...$this->arguments()]);
}
```

Laravel's documentation is focused solely on authoring custom commands and occasionally invoking other commands with `$this->call()` - it doesn't seem to cover extending existing functionality, or passing arguments through.

---

**Already Tried / Doesn't Work:**

- Creating a separate custom command like `php artisan migrate:core`. This will work exactly for the functionality I wish to add, and nothing else - it won't preserve any of `migrate`'s other options, which are also needed. The goal is to set context for `migrate`'s core functionality.
- Passing arguments through a custom command manually, like the examples above. I can get existing arguments with `$this->arguments()` and reattach them to the inner artisan call, but each argument also needs to be in the definition of the custom command - trying to pass an argument that isn't in the commands defined arguments causes the command to be rejected. There doesn't seem to be a way to just wildcard passthrough. Sure I can copy-paste migrate's existing argument definitions, but it won't be flexible with any future core changes or 3rd party packages.
- Creating a new custom command that extends `migrate` directly. Trying a proof-of-concept alias of the base `migrate`:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand;

class MigrateCore extends MigrateCommand {
    protected $signature = 'migrate:core';

    public function handle() {
        parent::handle();
    }
}
```

Results in a hairy `BindingResolutionException` from higher up Laravel's core hierarchy:

```
Target [Illuminate\Database\Migrations\MigrationRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Console\Commands\MigrateCore, Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator]
```

which, to me, feels like embarking on a path not intended.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://medium.com/hackernoon/extending-laravels-migration-command-to-add-new-options-90b5a0fc4ef4 Seems like the base migrate command should be extendable, although the article is a few years old.

Comment: @miken32 yeah, it was the first thing I tried. That article was written in 2017, so it's based on Laravel 5 at the latest - most of the syntax is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this as `app/Console/Commands/MigrateCore.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand;

class MigrateCore extends MigrateCommand {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $migrator = app("migrator");
        $dispatcher = app("events");
        $this->signature .= "{--core : Run core migrations}";
        parent::__construct($migrator, $dispatcher);
    }

    public function handle(): void
    {
        if ($this->option("core")) {
            $this->input->setOption("path", "database/migrations/core");
        }
        parent::handle();
    }
}
```

The error you were getting:

> "Target [Illuminate\Database\Migrations\MigrationRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Console\Commands\MigrateCore, Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator]"

is fairly cryptic, but if you look into the comments in `Illuminate\Container\Container` where the error is thrown, it starts to make a bit of sense:

> ```
> // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
> // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is
> // no binding registered for the abstractions so we need to bail out.
> ```

The constructor for `Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand` wants to be injected with an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator` which in turn is looking for a `Illuminate\Database\Migrations\MigrationRepositoryInterface`. But no concrete classes have been bound to that interface yet.

So, instead of just inheriting the constructor from `Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand` we initialize those bindings with the `app()` helper, and then pass them to the constructor.

Got a bit of help from [this Laracasts post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/target-illuminatedatabasemigrationsmigrationrepositoryinterface-is-not-instantiable).

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! I had to duplicate this for each subcommand e.g. `migrate:reset`, but it was easy to write a trait to keep the extension logic centralized on each copy.